# What to do if a shortcode already exists

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm writing a Worpress plugin that defines a shortcode.
What happens at shortcode registration if there's another shortcode already registered with that same name ?
What is the practice ? Is there a possibility to find the conflicting plugin so as to warn the user that he should deactivate it to be able to activate yours ??

Thanks.

```
if ( !shortcode_exists( 'myshortcode' ) ) {
    add_shortcode('myshortcode','mycallback');
}
else ?????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is allways to prefix the name of your shortcode in order to avoid naming collisions. You can use a particular prefix in relation with your plugin name or activity. You can see some guideline in the plugins development handbook here : https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/best-practices/#prefix-everything

My personal practice is to process with a personal name spacing format. It could give something like:

```
add_shotcode('company_plugin_shorcode');
```

Hope it helps

Comment: So unless you have a registered trademark that can constitute the prefix there is no absolutely reliable solution. Maybe Wordpress should manage a database of registered shortcodes...

Answer (score 1):

Asking the user to disable another plugin just because you can't register your shortcode with the name you want might not be the best idea for a variety of reasons.

Other things you could try instead:

- Name your shortcode something unique. For example, WooCommerce's shortcodes are all prefixed with *woocommerce_*: `[woocommerce_cart]`, `[woocommerce_checkout]`, et cetera.
- You could register an alternative shortcode if the name you want to use is already taken.

If you ask me, I'd go for #1.